# jaxb how to marshall values in some order?

Tags: java, jaxb

f.e I want to have an xml where values of my collection is stored in alphabetical order:

```
<tag1>a</tag1>
<tag1>b</tag1>
<tag1>c</tag1>
```

is it possible with jaxb?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use an ordered collection on the Java side of things.

**Root**

The `tag1` property is a `SortedSet`.  You could pass in a `Comparator` when you create the `TreeSet`:

```
package forum9096805;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private SortedSet<String> tag1 = new TreeSet<String>();

    public SortedSet<String> getTag1() {
        return tag1;
    }

    public void setTag1(SortedSet<String> tag1) {
        this.tag1 = tag1;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9096805;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.getTag1().add("b");
        root.getTag1().add("c");
        root.getTag1().add("a");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <tag1>a</tag1>
    <tag1>b</tag1>
    <tag1>c</tag1>
</root>
```

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Sure, go ahead :) Now I can get the upvotes for your work :) Unless I'm over my daily reputation cap.

Answer (score 2):

Question should be: **Is it possible in XSD (XML Schmea)?** And the answer is **NO**. But you can make sure the XML instance is containing the data in alphabetical order by using ordered collection like List implementations or an array.

Comment: Assuming Tichodroma answer works, **its possible** to change the collection type in schema. Example [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/01/jaxb-and-choosing-list-implementation.html)

Comment: @sergio91pt There is no notion of ordered collection (based on content) in schema. The link essentialy explains how to implement the suggestion I and Tichodroma provided.